# how to add two different selection models in extjs panel

Tags: extjs4.2

I have a grid with a customized selModel and cellediting plugin. Now I need to add also Checkbox Selection Model to it. Is this possible to have two selModels? Here is my existing code

```
        selModel: Ext.create('TTT.MultiCellSelectionModel', {
            mode: 'MULTI',
            allowDeselect: true
        }),
        multiSelect: true,
        selType: 'cellmodel'
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know its not possible for grid having more than one SelectionModel.
but it could be done if you override or make new SelectionModel class which have your requirement.

```
Ext.define('TTT.CustomSelectionModel', {
    extend: 'TTT.MultiCellSelectionModel',
    // you can put your logic here
})
```

But you will need extra time for it.